# Invariants of the symmetric group

Tags: rt.representation-theory, invariant-theory

Let $V_\lambda$ be an irreducible representation  of the symmetric group $S_n$ as usual labeled by parition $\lambda$ of $n.$

**Question.** 
Is there any general information about   the algebra of invariants $\mathbb{C}[V_\lambda]^{S_n}$: minimal generating set,  number of generators, constructive algorithms, usefull isomorphisms,  Hilbert series?

Comment: The Hilbert series of $\mathbb{C}[V]^G$ for any finite-dimensional representation of any finite (or even compact) group $G$ can be computed using Molien's theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molien_series

Comment: Of cource, but did you see such calculations for $\mathbb{C}[V_\lambda]^{S_n}$ ? any reference, please